# Windows XP with Ubuntu 14.04 on 2 separate hard drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-xp

I am new to Ubuntu. I have Windows XP Professional 32-bit on one 300GB IDE hard drive and Ubuntu 14.04 running on another 61GB IDE hard drive, and I cannot get my Windows XP to boot with Grub! When I select Windows XP from the boot menu, Grub just restarts my computer. The computer I have with those two hard drives is a Dell Optiplex GX240, so the hardware is old, and its BIOS won't let me change the boot priority on the two IDE hard drives.

What can I do now? Is there a step I missed when installing Ubuntu? Can I edit Grub to boot Windows XP without messing with the BIOS? Do I have to downgrade to an older release of Ubuntu to make it work? I am willing to reinstall Ubuntu, if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter up updating your grub while both hard drives are installed.  You can do the same thing with a pen drive installed.

While booted into Ubuntgu, run this command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Grub will search all your partitions for OS Installations and add them to your boot menu.  It will search partitions on all the drives.  So it doesn't matter is the OS installations (partitions) are on the same drive or different drives.  They will be found.

You can check the partitions that will be found by typing this command:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
```

There are numerous other commandlines and applications to check your partitions including the GUI's gparted and gnome-disk-utility.

Comment: I failed to mention that when I select Windows XP on GRUB.. it wont boot windows XP, it just restarts the computer

Comment: The answer for having Windows XP installed on separate drives is the simple answer I described.  Your new question is something you'd have to deal with in a Microsoft Forum.  How to repair a failed Windows Boot.  Grub won't fix Windows.  Windows is broke.  The simplest way would be to reinstall Windows.  The details of fixing Windows failed boot would have to be provided by a Microsoft support thread.